# Fragment or View on top of Map fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm working on an app where I want to display some overlay on top of a google map once the marker is clicked. I was wondering whether a view or a fragment would be the correct approach to this. I tried doing it with a fragment previously and it worked but I couldn't see the google map in the background, however now I'm doing it with a view and that works properly, however I still can move around in the map in the background with the view open, maybe there is some way to pause fragment interaction? Another question I have is, should I use a fragment or view? Is there some proper way to do this such that I can still display the maps in the background?
Here is an image of what I currently have after clicking the marker.

[image: MapsOverlay]

Comment: It has the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215855/fragment-layout-seems-to-not-be-interactive-clickable/50216427#50216427.

Answer (score 0):

Both Fragment and View are the correct approaches - it just depends on the amount of logic related to the overlay.

- When to use a `View`: when the overlay is just some kind of "popup" that does not do much (eg just displays text)
- When to use a `Fragment`: when the overlay has more logic and maybe a lifecycle, for example you have some kind of EditText and a Button and an API call and a progress indicator - you get the drift. It makes sense to separate this logic into a module to keep entities simple and contained.

By the way, for this kind of popup you could also use a Dialog, it will be easier to implement than a Fragment. [Here is a simple example.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs)

As to why you can still navigate the map despite the View being visible over it - try to add two attributes to this view in your XML:

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/yourView"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:focusable="true" />
```

It will make the view intercept all touch and not pass it further down the view tree.